Light/Shadow problem with eevee next
I'm brand new to Blender and recently decided to learn how to render on Eevee. I've only used Cycles so far because I preferred the style but I'd like to do some animation so I need to learn Eevee which allows me to render much faster.
So I decided to follow this step-by-step tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKZQaBkVcT4&t=1386s
I had no particular problems until I had to manage my lights in the volumetric fog...
Indeed, I was able to get a good result in my viewport, but once the rendering was finished, I had a scene with shadows flickering all over the place.
Here's an example:
https://youtube.com/shorts/X-Ti2t_r8-4?feature=share
(sorry idk how to add a video here, gifs allow 2MB max)
My other concern is that sometimes white dots appear and disappear where I've put pointlights in the buildings (visible on the GIF above).

I was very careful to hide each light behind a wall, so that they're never in direct contact with the camera, but there's no difference...
Also, in front of my ship, there's supposed to be a kind of headlight that's visible in certain angles in my viewport but invisible in the render, would you know why?
Am I setting up Eevee wrong? Are there any specific things to check before working with volumetric lights and fogs?
I'm using a MacBook Pro M2 max 32Gb RAM with Blender 4.2.2
Please let me know if you need more information about my scene or my Blender settings.
Thank you very much for your answers

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
